# Аюдаг, Карадаг, Чатырдаг. Как писать? Слитно или через дефис?

Tags: ономастика

Аюдаг, Карадаг, Чатырдаг. Как писать? Слитно или через дефис?

Answer (score 2):

"Словарь имён собственных русского языка" за 2010 г. рекомендует **слитное** написание всех трёх приведённых вами названий.